# Intrusion detection

Tags: security, networking, intrusion-detection, intrusion-prevention

I've got a security project regarding the intrusion detection and prevention. I've been googling about it but didn't land up on something substantial. I'm supposed to submit an abstract as of now, I'd like to know how an IDPS is implemented and what all things to keep in mind while deploying an IDSP. Also suggestions regarding the programming implementation are welcome. I'd be better if you can suggest some reading web-resources.

Well I'm just a final year student of B.tech Computer science and this id kind of a new experience for me. So please don't pre-assume anything.

Thanks :)

Comment: @Anurag: Don't know if anyone is going to answer this, but you may end up with better luck asking this as a programming question.  Such as "what algorithms can I use to implement <x>".  Doing some research on your own first tends to win over more people, and avoid getting your question closed.

Comment: http://www.snort.org/

Comment: http://www.sans.org/security-resources/idfaq/

Comment: Keep in mind that you are moving to the dark side of the force. Take your place right next to door-to-door insurance salesmen and promotional trip organizers.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've already received links to [SANS](http://sans.org/), [Snort](http://www.snort.org), etc.  Allow me to steer you to some academic literature on the subject (since you mentioned this was in the context of an undergraduate degree):

> Readings in Intrusion Detection
>   http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~wenke/ids-readings.html
>
> International Symposium on Recent
>   Advances in Intrusion Detection
>   http://www.raid-symposium.org/
>
> USENIX Security Symposium
>   http://usenix.org/events/byname/security.html
>
> Workshop on Intrusion Detection and
>   Network Monitoring
>   http://usenix.org/publications/library/proceedings/detection99/technical.html

Lots more out there of course; consider [a more focused search](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=intrusion+detection) to find more published papers.